# Do you ever double dialogue takes in your mix or design/edit

Tags: dialogue

Just running across an old student film and remembered that the editor doubled several dialogue takes.  Does anybody here do this or hear of doing this for some reason or another?

It seems like a beginner method to me.

Answer (score 2):

I've encounter also this setup in some OMF's and I believe is for level issues. The editor's setup is not calibrated for cinema, instead most of the times is consisted of 2 tiny speakers.

Comment: The fact I usually have to drop an OMF globally by about 10-15dB on import before playback (wherein they did double or quad up takes to get more "gain), says enough.

Comment: Thats true!bring down the level bedore hit spacebar

Answer (score 2):

I just figured it was to double the voice and make it be louder or more impressive but still I'll chalk it up to a 1st year student editor..

Answer (score 2):

This is a pet peeve of mine.  I see this all the time in OMFs I get.  And I do mean all the time.  It seems like a pretty standard approach video editors take to make quiet clips louder.  If the volume is turned all the way up and the clip is still not loud enough they'll double it.  Drives me crazy, because then I have to sort through and delete the extraneous regions.  I just got an OMF recently where these extra clips were not even on adjacent tracks, they were scattered all over the place.  Is it not possible to add another gain stage in final cut?

Answer (score 1):

Was that to achieve a special effect? Or if not, what was the intention do you think?

Answer (score 1):

I edit for animated feature films, and we sometimes use the double up method to increase the volume of a dialogue clip, sometimes the recorded dialogue track is so soft that even when we crank up the levels to max it is still too soft. When we are in a rush we use this method

Answer (score 0):

I vaguely remember that being a way to achieve a stereo sound from a mono mic feed. But unsure why. Maybe on earlier systems pan L R was controlled by track placement (A1, A2, etc., rather than a specific pan control for each track.

Answer (score 0):

S/he wasn't just cutting between the best takes?

Answer (score 0):

It's often done in music to create a fatter sound, but it has to be really tight to work.

Edit: Or was he duplicating it? In that case he might have put an effect on one of the tracks and used it as an aux send